# User.Identity return wrong user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Currently we are developing 2 websites, but they share one database, and the 2 websites both use Identity for user management, e.g. login, account setting etc.

The identity user entity definition for website A and website B are as below

```
public class UserA : IdentityUser
{
    ...

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<UserA > manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class UserB : IdentityUser
{
    ...

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<UserB > manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

The UserA and UserB entities are mapped to different tables in the database.

The problem is as below

- Launch the website A and B in the same browser
- login website B -- no problem
- login website A -- no problem
- Refresh the index page of website B, the username show the one logged into website A which is wrong, the username is got as below in the cshtml:

  ```
  <div>@User.Identity.Name</div>
  ```

Any ideas or do I need to provide some more detailed information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s using cookies to track the logged in user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, so that’s the expected behavior. You’d have to use something like Chrome profiles if you want to enable what you’re trying to do, or you could rename the cookie for one of the applications. Something like this, http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/07/rename-authentication-cookie-name-of-asp-net-identity/.